# Filter Strings in Array for Specific Attributes Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, filter, character, filenames

I have a column of strings in a table representing the filenames in a folder as produced by the `dir` function.

```
tmpList = struct2table(dir('myFolder'));
```

The folder contains many different file types and folders. I want only the excel files and I can find these by using:

```
filesData = [dir(['myFolder','\*.xlsx']);dir(['myFolder','\*.xls'])];
```

However how do I expand this/ replace this such that I can filter `tmpList.name` to include only files which have the following attributes:

- First three letters are: 'DTE' (which occurs as both caps or small case)
- All the characters following DTE are only numbers (and only numbers between 6 and 8 characters long)
- Extension is .xlsx or .xls

example, for the following list only 1 and 2 are identified to keep:

1. 'DTE123456.xlsx'
2. 'Dte01234567.xls'
3. 'abc12345678.xlsx'
4. 'DTE12345c34.xls'
5. 'DTE123456.doc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression to find file names which meet your criteria and then `cellfun` to find indexes of those file names in `tmpList`:

```
tmpList = struct2table(dir('myFolder')); % your beginning

filteredTmpList = regexpi(tmpList.name(:), '^dte\d{6,8}\.xlsx?$', 'match');
finalList = tmpList(~cellfun('isempty',filteredTmpList), :);
```